# Regex to match $ symbol followed by any word and keep the word

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex pattern for this but to no avail. Here are some examples of what I need. `[]` represents an array as output.

Input

```
Hello $World
```

Output

```
[$World]
```

Input

```
My name is $John Smith and I like $pancakes
```

Output

```
[$John, $pancakes]
```

I managed to come up with this, it matches the pattern but doesn't keep the words it finds.

```
String test = "My name $is John $Smith";
String[] testSplit = test.split("(\\$\\S+)");
System.out.println(testSplit);
```

Output

```
[My name ,  John ]
```

As you can see, it's completely swallowing the words I need, more specifically, the words that match the pattern. How can I have it return an array with only the words I need? (as shown in the examples)

Comment: You might want to take a look at what `split()` does: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html. Maybe you want. Try to change it to `match()` instead.

Comment: I know of the existence of `split()` and `match()`. `split()` specifically uses regex to work, and therein lies the question. The question isn't about the method but more about the regex needed to make it work.

Comment: Your regex is working. You are just using it the wrong way :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split` takes a regex, and specifically splits the string *around* that regex, so that what it splits on is not retained in the output. If you want what it found to split around, you should use the `Matcher` class, for example:

```
String line = "My name $is John $Smith";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\$\\S+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

This will find all the matches of a pattern in a String and print them out. These are the same strings that `split` will use to divide up a string.

Comment: same answer at the same time. Good one :D.

Comment: What's the difference between `matcher.group()` and `matcher.group(1)` Tried both and both have the same output.

Comment: In this case it's the same because you only have one matching group. Check the specs of `group(int)` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)

Comment: Yes I believe `matcher.group()` is the same as `matcher.group(0)`, i.e. the entire input that was matched. Here it's unnecessary to use capture groups, but to me it is more natural to use them just in case you want to match on something slightly different from what you're searching for.

Comment: Correct. `matcher.group()` captures the whole expression just as `matcher.group(0)` does.

Answer (score 3):

`split` just uses your pattern to separate strings. If you want to return the matched string, try something like this:

```
String test = "My name $is John $Smith";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(\\$\\S+)");
Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(test);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); 
}
```

Comment: `while (matcher.find())`

Comment: I don't believe the parentheses in the regex are necessary.

Comment: I just used the OP's regex which was matching. Maybe you are right on that one as well.